# Computing probability of a class from cluster labels in hierarchical clustering?

Tags: python, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, entropy

I have a dataframe with two classes 'yes' and 'no'. using scipy Hiererchical clustering I found 2 clusters.  here is my code

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, dendrogram
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import fcluster
Mdist_matrix = pdist(x_Minmax, metric= 'cityblock')
MSlink = linkage (Mdist_matrix , method = 'single' , metric = 'cityblock')
crsm = fcluster(MClink, k , criterion='maxclust')
arr = np.unique(crsm, return_counts = True)
# print(arr)
dfcluster= dfcluster.copy()
dfcluster['Clabels'] = pd.Series(crsm, index=dfcluster.index)
No = dfcluster[df['status'] == 0]['Clabels'].value_counts()
print("CNO\n",No)
Yes= dfcluster[df['status'] == 1]['Clabels'].value_counts()
print("Cyes\n",Yes)
```

[The output looks like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjjqW.jpg)

I wanted to compute the entropy of each clusters and the purity of the the cluster.How can I compute the probability of 'yes' and 'no' in each of the clusters? 
I tried to do it in this way [Fastest way to compute entropy in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450192/fastest-way-to-compute-entropy-in-python) but it is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer for purity.
Your contingency matrix (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612982/what-is-the-difference-between-a-confusion-matrix-and-contingency-table) if you are not familiar with) is the following:

```
      |   1  |   2 |
------|------|-----|
 CNO  | 7244 | 544 |
------|------|-----|
 CYES | 2136 |  76 |
-------------------+
```

Then, there is a formula to compute purity from the contingency matrix:

```
purity_score = np.sum(np.amax(contingency_matrix, axis=0)) / np.sum(contingency_matrix)
```

Comment: got it ! Thank you.